# How to initialize dynamic fields generated with a ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

If I have in my view this html code, generated dinamically with `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in selectedProcedures track by $index">
    <span style="display:none;">{{item.id}}</span>

    <div class="row" ng-repeat="item2 in item.serviceComposite.designators">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-xl-10">
           <div>
               <button ng-click="hidePartBindings{{$parent.$index}} = !hidePartBindings{{$parent.$index}}" style="background: none; border: 0; float:left; text-align:center; margin-right: 5px;"><img src="./css/themes/parsek/img/layout/caret-blue.svg"/></button>
               <span id="serviceComposite{{$parent.$index}}">{{ item2.extension }}</span>
           </div>
           <div class="row" id="partBindings{{$parent.$index}}" ng-repeat="item4 in item.serviceComposite.partBindings" ng-show="hidePartBindings{{$parent.$index}} === false">
               <div ng-repeat="item5 in item4.part.designators">
                   <span class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12">
                       <a style="margin-left: 3rem;" href="#item-information" class="lightbox2" ng-click="checkIfIsModified({{item5.id}}, $event)">{{ item5.extension }}</a>
                   </span>
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I initialize all generated `hidePartBindings{{$parent.$index}}` to `true` in my controller?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of object is `hidePartBindings{{$parent.$index}}` supposed to be? If its a list then you should probably use square brackets - `hidePartBindings[$parent.$index]`. `ng-click` already expects an expression; You don't need curly braces there.

Comment: It's a boolean. Each button, when pressed, has to change the related boolean to not(previous_value).

Comment: Then use a list of booleans. Makes life much easier!

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider a controller for each instance of your repeated item. Of course, it would not be the best thing to do if you have hundreds of items.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item2 in item.serviceComposite.designators" ng-controller="ItemController">
```

If you had fewer items and wanted to go down the route of a controller for each item, it would be a simple case of setting `item.hideParts = true` in your item controller.